# How to query a MySql table with a where clause from another table?

Tags: mysql, join, datatables

I have two tables in a MySql database, one called sales and one called auctions. The sales table has an auction_id column. I want to extract sales which were only made in EUR, but the currency is a column in the auctions table. What query should I run to achieve this? Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use a `JOIN`?

Comment: I have tried SELECT sale_price FROM sales INNER JOIN auctions ON currency WHERE currency IS 'eur';. I'm very new to MySql so I don't exactly know what I'm doing.

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it, along with the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output for that sample data

Comment: Apologies, it's been answered but I shall do next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using inner query

```
select * 
from sales 
where auction_id in (select id from auctions where currency='EUR');
```

what it will do

- first it will run inner query and select all id having currency EUR.
- after it will check if sales contain the auction_id which being selected from inner query

Other option is also available that is using join

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales, auctions 
WHERE sales.auction_id = auctions.id AND auctions.currency='EUR'
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales 
JOIN auctions ON sales.auction_id = auctions.id AND auctions.currency='EUR'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i've learnt a lot from it.

Comment: Only last version is safe (but you forget about WHERE). Do not use WHERE IN and/or comma-separated cartesian until there is no JOIN alternative.

Comment: thank you @Akina for updating my knowledge when I started learning I do the same mistakes but now I have changed with JOIN.

Comment: Add `where auctions.currency='EUR'` to the last 2 queries.

Comment: Thank you very much I will use the last 2 queries.